# Update Custom List when to do item is completed

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I am using Sharepoint On-Prem (the free version) and what I'm trying to achieve I thought would be simple.  But I am very new to Sharepoint and coding so I am not sure how.

I have a custom list, that when an item is created it starts a workflow and assigns a to-do item to a user.  That's working great.

So the user gets an e-mail follows the link to the to-do item, Clicks Edit ...

And here is my problem.  I want the user to enter some information (Specifically select a date which is unlikely to be today's date) and click Complete.  I want that information to be updated in the task (probably in the due date field).  This will then get transferred back to my original list through a workflow.

So my question is this.  Is it possible to edit the .aspx file through Sharepoint Designer to add an editable date field in the form, and update the task list?  And if so, how do I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion, you should not edit the `.aspx` file from designer. There are following ways you can prefer:

**1. Using InfoPath Form (Old School Way)**
You can create an Edit form using InfoPath forms (dont forget to make it default edit form as well). Where you can set validation rule.

**2: Using JS `PreSaveAction()` method**
You can add a content editor web part to your edit form page, and place some JS code. There are `PreSave` and `PostSave` methods available in SharePoint for this purpose. [Follow the link to explore more](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31330.sharepoint-using-presaveaction-function-on-custom-list-forms.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and I appreciate that this is not the best way in your opinion.  However, as I said, I'm new to Sharepoint, Sharepoint Designer is the only thing I know.  I have not found a way to add a web part to a default form.I don't have infopath, and wouldn't know what I'm doing with it anyway.  I would prefer to complete this the way that I understand.  I have been able to add static information to the form in this method.

Comment: Are comfortable with JS?

Comment: I can read it (mostly), I can modify it, but can't really write it from scratch.

Comment: and do you have idea on DOM? How to search for ID, Class in HTML?

Comment: i can provide you with the steps and code, but you need to have atleast DOM idea, how to extract ID, Classes etc. or how to travel in DOM.

Comment: I am not sure what DOM is.

Comment: DOM is basically the HTML markups. If I provide the JS solution which can help, still you need to figure out, your input columns IDs/class or other attribute in order to make that script execute properly in your environment.

Comment: Ahhh right, yes I have some idea on that.  I should be able to follow it.